# Name for anti-decoy

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

There is this trick when you give a person two choices: one which you want her to accept; and the other, which is significantly worse than the first one. This way you create the illusion of choice, and also make the first option look better when contrasted with the second.

In some sense this is anti-decoy: a decoy must attract, while this fake option must repel.

Is there a name for this second, fake option?

Comment: It sounds like a forced choice.

Comment: You said it yourself, the word is "_repellant_".

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: but "decoy" isn't quite the same as "attraction"; it has more specific meaning

Comment: **[Decoy Synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/decoy):** _bait, trap, imitation, allure, attract_. I would very much say that decoy has a lot to do with attraction!

Comment: Do either of these appeal? A *to shunt* is to shove aside, turn away, sidetrack, or to divert. A *Submarine Signal and Decoy Ejector (SSDE)* is a warfare countermeasure, ejected by a submarine to falsely attract a torpedo. By the way, when I was editor of a technical magazine, I had a designer who would present his favored choice and a lousy alternative. That was his way of getting me to do it his way while maintaining my illusion of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  fake option might be called a  *[straw man](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/straw_man#Noun)* (“An insubstantial concept, idea, endeavor or argument, particularly one deliberately set up to be weakly supported, so that it can be easily knocked down; especially to impugn the strength of any related thing or idea”).

A term that almost works, but probably not quite:  *[stalking horse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stalking_horse#Noun)* (“A horse used as cover by a hunter stalking game” or “A candidate put forward instead of any of several potentially successful candidates in order to initiate a leadership debate, gauge feelings, divide opposition etc”).

While plausible and perhaps suitable meanings for “forced choice” and “mental forcing” have been suggested in another answer, note that both terms already have some currency with different meanings; *[forced choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_choice)* referring to [ipsative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ipsative#Adjective) questions (“a measure that forces an individual to choose among multiple desirable options”), and   *[mental forcing](http://www.spring.org.uk/2008/08/psychology-of-magic-3-critical.php)* referring to either [psychology-of-magic](http://www.spring.org.uk/2008/08/psychology-of-magic-3-critical.php) or to [certain beliefs](http://mentalforcingstory.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 3):

This type of situation is often referred to as [Hobson's choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice) (or [Hobbs' choice](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_origin_of_Hobb%27s_choice)).

It's from Thomas Hobson (1544-1631), a livery stable owner who offered customers the choice of either taking the horse in the stall nearest the door, or taking none at all (to make sure his best horses didn't get overused). Effectively, the "choice" was just *take it or leave it*.

Thus some people will say the expression implies your only choice is to accept or reject a single option on offer. But in my experience it's also commonly used where superficially there are two or more actual choices available, but all except one are manifestly unacceptable. That's to say, it can be used in situations where there's the *illusion* of choice, but only one is option is practical.

The best term I can think of for the "fake" alternative is ***bogus*** (or ***sham***) *choice/option/offer*. I don't see that "decoy" fits very well, because usually a decoy is something you're *intended* to fall for.

Comment: I think this is different in that Hobbs' choice is between something and nothing. The question seems to be asking about a choice between two somethings (also it seems to be about the somethings, not the choice itself, but that's beside the point of my comment)

Comment: @horatio: You're obviously one of the *"some people"* I referred to in my second paragraph. But noting the popularity of the "eggcorn" form [Hobbesian choice](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21445/what-is-a-hobbesian-trap) (as well as *Hobbs' choice*) there's obviously scope for some *other* people to assume a different meaning as well as a different etymology. Besides, in OP's example, one of the choices isn't really a credible option anyway, so it's either take the "real" option or go without.

Comment: Sorry — my question wasn't clear. I am asking about the name of the fake option.

Comment: @R C: Yeah - Hobson's choice doesn't usually refer to the "fake option". It refers to the *situation* where there isn't really a choice on offer in the first place. I'll edit for the revised question text.

Answer (score 0):

In magic, this is called a "forced choice" or "mental forcing"

Comment: Sorry — my question wasn't clear. I am asking about the name of the fake option.